# How often are the drivers updated on the GA linux-generic kernel?

Tags: drivers, kernel

I know that the drivers of the kernel HWE is update every six month with the release LTS.
But I not find other info with the GA kernel.

Know you this info?

Thank you.

Comment: The HWE upgrades every six months (*for the first two years*); the GA kernel option is the more *stable* option (and default for many ISOs for this reason, such as Server) as it does not change (*security fixes only are back-ported to it*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HWE upgrades every six months (*for the first two years; with stacks from the non-LTS & next LTS*)

> The Ubuntu LTS enablement (also called HWE or Hardware Enablement)
> stacks provide newer kernel and X support for existing Ubuntu LTS
> releases. These enablement stacks can be installed manually but are
> also available when installing with Ubuntu LTS point release media.
> These newer enablement stacks are meant for desktop and server and
> even recommended for cloud or virtual images.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

The GA kernel option is generally seen as the more *stable* option **as it does not change**, with *security fixes only back-ported to it*.

The GA kernel stack is default for

- Ubuntu Server LTS
- [Ubuntu *flavors*](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) for the first & .1 ISO only

The HWE kernel stack is default for

- Ubuntu Desktop LTS (20.04 & later)
- Ubuntu *flavors* .2 & later ISOs